# ASP.net is user in role

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I'm having trouble working out how to quickly find out yes/no is a username in a role?  I've gotten as far as:

```
Roles.FindUsersInRole("Admin", usersName)
```

But am a bit stuck, any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The below returns true or false depending on if the specified user is in the specified role

```
Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, role)
```

So, for example, if you wanted to remove a user from a specific role you could use

```
 if (Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, role))
         Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(userName, role);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way just with

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")) 
{
    // Code Here... 
}
```