# How to check user is in administrator group or not

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

How to get User's group or User is in admin group or not ?

I am using .NET framework 3.5 web application.

I get the user name as follows:

```
   Dim strUser As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper
```

Now, I need to check whether this user is in admin group or not ? OR else, get the user's all group.

Please share me some stuff which helps me to achieve this.

Thank You.

Comment: Sorry, checked the wrong duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244489/asp-net-is-user-in-role

Comment: check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var isAdmin =((System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal)this.HttpContext.User).IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

Comment: But, username will be get from user context as this is web application. so, i do have username string as "domainname\username" for which i need to check.

Comment: giving error as `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal'.`

Comment: use this code as `Dim r As Boolean = CType(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal).IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)`

Comment: `Dim r As Boolean = CType(HttpContext.Current.User, System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal).IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.W‌​indowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)` this worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 admins than you can use the following two ways to determine if hes admin or to which group he/she belongs

1>  Alter the database table
  Add one more row to user login database to accept integer values, name it any thing you want or name it as group
now if the user is admin group then pass 1 to all the admins 2 to employees and accordingly
later where you want to check to which group he or she belongs just check what group value he or she has!

2>  If you have less no of people to be sorted
  put their names in code itself and use string compare!
  Although i suggest you go with the 1st method! its a good practice!